# Line Break with Pango

Tags: line-breaks, pango

According to [this documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html), Pango is able to handle some convenience tags like `<b>` for bold, or `<i>` for italic.

However, there's nothing for line break, like the commonly used `<br>`. Is there a way to make Pango able to handle line break?

Answer (score 7):

Through some guesswork and trial and error, I've discovered that carriage return (`\r`), not newline (`\n`), will cause pango to insert a break.